# How can I remove a RegistryValue on uninstall without removing the parent RegistryKey with WIX?

Tags: wix, multiple-instances, registrykey

If I use the follow code then nothing is removed on uninstall.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
  <Component Guid="xyz" Id="instance_path" MultiInstance="yes">
    <RegistryKey ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" Id="instance_path_reg" Key="Software\i-net software GmbH\i-net Test\Instances" Root="HKLM">
      <RegistryValue Name="[INSTANCE_NUMBER]" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLDIR]"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

If I replace `ForceCreateOnInstall="yes"` with `ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes"` then all is removed on uninstall.

But I want only remove the RegistryValue of this instance. The values of other instances should not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the property `INSTANCE_NUMBER` was not set on uninstall. The uninstaller has try to delete a not existing key.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the RemoveRegistryValue and leave your current entries. It is a little messy but should get the job done.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removeregistryvalue.html